# How do I type Square character

Tags: unicode, characters

I have to write x/100000 with square character: x*10-5 ,but the '-5' should be above 10 so it is known that it is x/10/10/10/10/10.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get x*10<sup>-5</sup>, as you would write it by hand, then your only option is your word processor's superscript option for text (unless you have a full equation editor feature handy).

The only superscript characters I know of in Unicode are 1, 2, 3 (listed as sup1, sup2 and sup3 respectively in [this reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/bycodes.html)) and those characters that are naturally above the centre-line (such as the degree symbol).

The common way of representing such a math clause in plain text is `x*10^-5` (this is how it would be represented in most programming languages).

Comment: I use ctrl+shift+= in ms word. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can copy-paste superscript numbers (and minus sign) from here: ⁻ ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹

These can also be helpful: ½ ⅓ ⅔ ⅕ ⅖ ⅗ ¼ ¾ ⅘ ⅙ ⅚ ⅛ ⅜ ⅝ ⅞

Comment: Great idea to make them available for copying, thanks! Weirdly, the 123 are not the same height as the rest of the numbers…

Comment: @w00t Depends on the font you use. Try it on the surface you wish to use it to see if it is visible there.

Comment: @w00t, they're the same height if you use the higher unicode values rather than the old fashioned ISO-8859-1 values. Note: ⁰ ⁱ ⁲ ⁳ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹. Alas, not all display fonts include all characters. Experimentation is key. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The most common superscripts of 1, 2 and 3 were included in ISO-8859-1, but a full superscript number set is available in Unicode.

U+207B is `⁻`, and U+2075 is `⁵`. In HTML, you can represent these with:

```
&#x207B;&#x2075;
```

Details are available from http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf, which is authoritative.

More information is also [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean in a word processor of some sort, you probably want to format the '-5' as superscript.

Also, if it's '-5', then is isn't a square character. It's only squaring when it's raised to the power of two.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. The 'superscript' and 'subscript'. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Mac, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and you will get an Emoji popup. Then, type the number you want (2) and the square will be part of the results

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about that one!  Thanks!  :)